# Image files occupying too much space on sdcard and emulator performance is degrading

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I have stored eight images into sdcard (size: 500mb). The size of each image ranges from 9-11 mb. I have some applications running on the emulator, which occupies 11 mb space and still I have 474 mb free space. Now, I want to add some more photos (Say 20) to already existing images. When I try to do this, the images are uploading very slowly and also I can see the size on sdcard is also increasing very much for that image. You can see that in the following image - [image]

What might be the reason for this? Is there any optimistic way to deal with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: increase memory card size and try

Answer (score 0):

I have reduced my image file size to 10kb. This worked for me.